# Show if measures are finite and agree on open intervals they agree on all elements of borel sig algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $\mu,\nu$ be measures such that $\mu((a,b))=\nu((a,b))<\infty$ for all $a<b \in \Bbb{R}$. And let $X=\Bbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be the Borel sigma algebra on $X$, show $\mu(A)=\nu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathbf{B}$. Here is my proof sketch so far using hints provided by the professor to first show they agree on all intervals regardless of length being infinite or including or exlcuding endpoints, then show they agree on finite unions of intervals then apply monotone class theorem. Ive done the first two and wanna make sure I did them correctly, ill take an upvote in meaning im on the right path. (Also, ive seen other solutions here but I wanted to do it using hints provided to us by the prof., and I came up with all of this on my own :))

(NOTE: if the index is just an $n$ it is implies $n \in \Bbb{N}$, finite unions or intersections are indicated as being finite by upper and lower indices.)

$\textbf{Attempt at proof:}$

Using the hint we show
$$\mathbf{A}=\{A \in \mathbf{B}: \mu(A)=\nu(A)\}$$
is a $\sigma-$algebra. First we show $\mu((a,b])=\nu((a,b])$ and that $\mu([a,b])=\nu([a,b]).$ Note that
$$[a,b]=(a,b) \cup \{a\}\cup \{b\}.$$
For any point, say $a$, one has (since we dont know if the measures give value of $0$ to points, they COULD be counting measures or who knows, so it suffices to show they agree on $a$ and on $b$)
$$\{a\}=(a-1,a+1) \setminus (a-1,a) \cup (a,a+1).$$
Thus by additivity of $\mu,\nu$ and finiteness of the intervals and subtraction we have that
\begin{align}
    \mu(\{a\})&=\mu((a-1,a+1) \setminus (a-1,a) \cup (a,a+1))\\
    &=\mu((a-1,a+1)) - \mu((a-1,a))+\mu((a,a+1))\\
    &=\nu((a-1,a+1)) - \nu((a-1,a))+\nu((a,a+1))\\
    &=\nu((a-1,a+1) \setminus (a-1,a) \cup (a,a+1))\\
    &=\nu(\{a\}).
\end{align}
And the same holds for $b \in \Bbb{R}$. Then
\begin{align}
    \mu([a,b])&=\mu((a,b))+\mu(\{a\})+\mu(\{b\})\\
    &=\nu((a,b))+\nu(\{a\})+\nu(\{b\})\\
    &=\nu([a,b])
\end{align}
The case for $[a,b)$ is the same except we only remove a single point. For showing $\mu((a,\infty))=\nu((a,\infty))$, note
$$(a,\infty)=\bigcup_n (a,a+n).$$
Let $A_n=(a,a+n)$. And set
$$B_n:=A_n \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j.$$
And it is clear that $\bigcup_n B_n = \bigcup_n A_n$. Thus we have
\begin{align}
\mu((a,\infty))&=\mu(\bigcup_n A_n)\\
    &=\mu(\bigcup_n B_n) && \text{as $\bigcup_n B_n = \bigcup_n A_n$}\\
    &=\mu(\bigcup_n A_n \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j) && \text{definition of $B_n$}\\
    &=\sum_n \mu(A_n \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j) && \text{disjointness of the sets and that $\mu$ is a measure}\\
    &=\sum_n \nu (A_n \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j) && \text{as $\mu,\nu$ agree on finite intervals} \\
    &=\nu(\bigcup_n A_n \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j) && \text{as $\nu$ is a measure and disjointness}\\
    &=\nu(\bigcup_n B_n) && \text{definition of $B_n$}\\
    &=\nu(\bigcup_n A_n) && \text{as $\bigcup_n B_n = \bigcup_n A_n$}\\
    &=\nu((a,\infty)).
\end{align}
Thus $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on all intervals regardless of end points included or not or infinite length. Next, by the hint, we show $\mu,\nu$ agree on a finite union of intervals. Put
$$A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^k (a_n,b_n).$$
I claim that $\mu(A)=\nu(A)$. In the spirit of forming disjoint sets, define $A_n:=(a_n,b_n)$.  And put
$$B_n:= A_n \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j.$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
    \mu(A)&=\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^k A_n)\\
    &=\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^k B_n) && \text{as $\cup_n B_n = \cup_n A_n$}\\
    &=\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^k A_n \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j) && \text{defnition of $B_n$} \\
    &=\sum_{n=1}^k \mu(A_n \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{n-1}) && \text{as $\mu$ is a measure and $B_n$ are disjoint}\\
    &=\sum_{n=1}^k \nu(A_n \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{n-1}) &&\text{as $\mu$,$\nu$ agree on intervals}\\
    &=\nu(\bigcup_{n=1}^k A_n \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j)&& \text{as $\nu$ is a measure and disjointness}\\
    &= \nu(\bigcup_{n=1}^k B_n) && \text{definition of $B_n$}\\
    &=\nu(\bigcup_{n=1}^k A_n)&& \text{as $\cup_n B_n = \cup_n A_n$}\\
    &=\nu(A).
\end{align}
As we have that intervals are closed under finite union and complements, the closure of complements follows from the fact that the complement of a bounded interval is the union of 2 rays which we showed have the same measure under $\mu,\nu$. Thus if $\mathbf{A}_0$ is the collection of disjoint unions of intervals, it is an algebra.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: @Andrew thanks!

Comment: This is an example where the $\pi$-$\lambda$ lemma is a lot more convenient than monotone class.  It's pretty much tailor made, in fact.

Comment: We haven’t learned that yet @NateEldredge